# I can't get the parsing-options of ImportJSON to work

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets

`=ImportJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin")`

works, but:

`=ImportJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin","/name","noHeaders")`

doesn`t.

---

I tried different Versions of the ImportJSON Script... hmm no luck so far

Here's the Link to my Google Sheets File :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eYwB3mL71Nrpuq7CAJEb1fuCF2yavD-LQt-CxoxYa4M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Instead of "," I had to use ";"

so this works perfectly:

```
=ImportJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin";"/name";"noHeaders")
```

Comment: I can only do that "in 19 hours" - don't know why. Thanks for reminding!